# I want to use HtmlUnit to collect news comments(Asynchronous Web Page)

Tags: web-crawler, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to collect news comments.
(http://v.media.daum.net/v/20170111104708176)

The title and body were successfully collected.

But because it(news comments) works asynchronously, I can not collect comments with HtmlUnit.

When I run Network Trace in Chrome, it calls the API internally and it does not work in HtmlUnit. (http://comment.daum.net/apis/v1/posts/17542278/comments?parentId=0&offset=3&limit=10&sort=RECOMMEND)

Here is the my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlHeading3;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSection;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {



        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

        String seedURL="http://v.media.daum.net/v/20170111104708176";

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(seedURL);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10 * 1000);

        String title ="";
        String content ="";

        title = ((HtmlHeading3)page.getByXPath("//*[@id='cSub']/div[1]/h3").get(0)).getTextContent();//news title       
        content = ((HtmlSection)page.getByXPath("//*[@id='harmonyContainer']/section").get(0)).getTextContent();//news contents
        System.out.println(title); 
        System.out.println(content); 
        HtmlDivision reply =    ((HtmlDivision)page.getByXPath("//*[@id='alex-area']").get(0));//news reply
        System.out.println(reply.asXml());// No have child elements...T.T

    }

}
```

Help me please

P.S : Here is HtmlUnit Maven Code.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: At first switch to the latest version of htmlunit. Do you get any log Output?